# i tried 'import pymysql' in python tkinter module, but its showing me pymsql is not named

Tags: python, module, pymysql

[image]

The code below is what I typed that developed the error message.

Error message: *pymsql is not named*.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import pymysql
def adminLogin():
    global nameVar
    global passwordVar

    username=nameVar.get()
    password=passwordVar.get()

    conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost', passwd='',user='root', db='billingsystem')
    cursor=conn.cursor()

    query="select * from user where username='{}' and password='{}'".format(username, password)
    cursor.execute(query)
    data=cursor.fetchall()
    admin=false

    for row in data:
        admin=true
    conn.close()
    if admin:
        mainwindow()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('invalid user', 'credentials entered are invalid')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed the pymysql module? `pip install PyMySQL`

Comment: if you have `pymysql` installed check for the project interpreter. Is the correct interpreter is set in which you have `pymysql` library installed

Comment: Could you show us the _exact_ error message?

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code and errors. Take the time to properly cut, paste, and format the code and error messages.

Comment: tnx ill check it out, i taught the my pymysql module came with  xampp..alright, i wont do that again @BryanOakley

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `PyMySQL` is installed. To to this, press Windows key + R and then type cmd and press enter. Type `pip install PyMySQL` and try again

Comment: it gave an error message that says, windows cannot find pip